# FB Feed dialog not asking for user comments

Tags: iframe, facebook

Why FB Feed dialog below (iframe solution) is not asking for user comments on dialog, the dialog appears and post is sent-

```
function callback() 
{
     alert("Thank you");
}

function showFeed() 
{
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
    FB.Facebook.init('kkkc', '/facebook/xd_receiver.htm', null); 
    FB.ensureInit(function() {

    var tpl_data ={"images":[{"src":"logo.gif","href":"kkk"}],"city":" "};
    var user_message_prompt = "What do you think of this ?";
    var user_message = {value: "write your comments here"};tData= {};
    FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(439384, tpl_data, null, null, null, 
    FB.RequireConnect.require, callback,user_message_prompt, user_message);
}
```

(added extra null to code, still not working !) 
NOTE: with Firefox the dialog seem to remain as blank when clicking Next, until closing from upper corner X.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a parameter.  That places your last 4 parameters out of order, which means that Facebook probably isn't receiving your user_message_prompt and user_message properly.

You need an extra 'null' in there for the story_size parameter.  Try this:

```
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(43932059084, tpl_data, null, null, null,
    FB.RequireConnect.require, null,user_message_prompt, user_message);
```

Comment: My callback function started to work indeed when adding a null, but still facebook dialog is not asking for any custom message??

Comment: Hmm... did you mean to change the template bundle id?  In your code above now it says '439384' instead of '43932059084'.